# How can I use chips like a tag sorter in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I will need more help, because I only have basic knowledge in JavaScript and I have been worried about it for 3 days and I can't put it together. I know I ask a lot but I am stuck and I have no idea how to make it works. I want the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <!-- here i want display all used tags -->
  </div>
  <div class="images">
   <img />
   <!-- here i want display all images which contains selected tags -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Defined in code I have this as follows

```
data: function () {
  return {
    images: [
        {
          tags: ["art"],
          url: "url of image",
          name: "my image name",
        },
        {
          tags: ["chipmunk", "art"],
          url: "url of image",
          name: "my image name",
        },
        {
          tags: ["ship"],
          url: "url of image",
          name: "my image name",
        },
        {
          tags: ["art", "ship"],
          url: "url of image",
          name: "my image name",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

I want:

**1**. A feature that automatically searches for this images Array and finds all tags and displays them in `.tags` as `<li>` each. Selectable and each only once and sorted alphabet) without having to write them in my own Array.

**2**. A feature that automatically displays all images that contain a selected tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, try like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      images: [{tags: ["art"], url: "https://picsum.photos/50", name: "my image name",}, {tags: ["chipmunk", "art"], url: "https://picsum.photos/51", name: "my image name",}, {tags: ["ship"], url: "https://picsum.photos/49", name: "my image name",}, {tags: ["art", "ship"], url: "https://picsum.photos/48", name: "my image name",},],
      tags: [],
      selected: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const set = new Set([])
    this.images.forEach(i => set.add(...i.tags))
    this.tags = [...set]
  },
  computed: {
    getItems() {
      if(this.selected.length) {
        return this.images.filter(i => {
          return this.selected.every(s => i.tags.includes(s) )
        })
      }
      return this.images 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectTag(tag) {
      this.selected = !this.selected.includes(tag) ? [...this.selected, tag] : this.selected.filter(s => s !== tag)
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.tags, .container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <template class="" v-for="tag in tags">
      <button @click="selectTag(tag)">{{ tag }}</button>
    </template>
  </div>
  <div class="tags" v-if="selected.length">
    <template v-for="sel in selected">
      <p>{{ sel }}</p>
    </template>
  </div>
  <div class="tags">
    <div v-for="img in getItems">
      <p>{{ img.name }}</p>
      <img :src="img.url" />
      <p>{{ img.tags }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just 2 small things yet. If no tag is selected, show all images. I want tag to work as "Active" and "Inactive". I want to be able to cancel it on Click Like Activate it (toggle i mean, not just select)

Comment: @TheCzechTayen  check again pls I updated my answer

Comment: Ok nice. One more small little thing please. Show images if they contain all selected tags. I mean, if I choose 2 tags, I just want pictures that both of these tags have.

Comment: just change `some` with `every` :)

Comment: Oh nice. U really helped me. Last question. How i can use multilanguage i18n plugin with this? I mean which line i must to edit? Syntax is "this.$t(variable)"

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it via Discord this i18n plugin. Your code works perfectly. Saved a lot of time, thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251614/discussion-between-theczechtayen-and-nikola-pavicevic).